# Permission for translating menu items via the menu config screen

Tags: routes, users, i18n-l10n

I have a multi language Drupal site, Using i18n and the entity translation approach. Translating menu items from an node works well, but not all the menu items are driven by the nodes.

Now as user/1, I have permission to translate any menu item from the menu config screen:
/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu. I am trying to enable the same permissions for other roles/users. The second role has permissions to administer menu items and translate all entities, but for the life of me I cant figure out why the translate link doesn't show in the menu config screen for the other role. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You have to have the following permissions set: *translate interface*  and *administer menu items*.

Comment: Can you expand this answer a little bit so it could help out future readers?  Thanks.